# how to group json using jq and then convert to yaml

Tags: json, yaml, jq, yq

I have this json that i want to convert.

```json
[
  {
    "externalGroup": "another group admins",
    "groupId": "da2e42c8-6423-4d32-99b5-5fc58f9f80b8"
  },
  {
    "externalGroup": "another group users",
    "groupId": "7c69cac1-4a70-4170-8251-cde3762fe498"
  },
  {
    "externalGroup": "my group admin",
    "groupId": "e08a1d9d-f108-4e87-bdb3-ee4f10c6752a"
  },
  {
    "externalGroup": "my group users",
    "groupId": "8370821e-edfa-4615-ac2e-47815b740f40"
  },
  {
    "externalGroup": "some group",
    "groupId": "e08a1d9d-f108-4e87-bdb3-ee4f10c6752a"
  },
  {
    "externalGroup": "some group",
    "groupId": "8370821e-edfa-4615-ac2e-47815b740f40"
  },
  {
    "externalGroup": "some group",
    "groupId": "7c69cac1-4a70-4170-8251-cde3762fe498"
  }
]
```

I have tried this, which is pretty close:
`jq '. | group_by(.externalGroup)[] | {(.[0].externalGroup): map(.groupId)}'`

I get this:

```json
{
  "another group admins": [
    "da2e42c8-6423-4d32-99b5-5fc58f9f80b8"
  ]
}
{
  "another group users": [
    "7c69cac1-4a70-4170-8251-cde3762fe498"
  ]
}
{
  "my group admin": [
    "e08a1d9d-f108-4e87-bdb3-ee4f10c6752a"
  ]
}
{
  "my group users": [
    "8370821e-edfa-4615-ac2e-47815b740f40"
  ]
}
{
  "some group": [
    "e08a1d9d-f108-4e87-bdb3-ee4f10c6752a",
    "8370821e-edfa-4615-ac2e-47815b740f40",
    "7c69cac1-4a70-4170-8251-cde3762fe498"
  ]
}
```

But this doesn't convert properly with yq. It would need to look something like this instead:

```json
{
  "another group admins": [
    "da2e42c8-6423-4d32-99b5-5fc58f9f80b8"
  ],
  "another group users": [
    "7c69cac1-4a70-4170-8251-cde3762fe498"
  ],
  "my group admin": [
    "e08a1d9d-f108-4e87-bdb3-ee4f10c6752a"
  ],
  "my group users": [
    "8370821e-edfa-4615-ac2e-47815b740f40"
  ],
  "some group": [
    "e08a1d9d-f108-4e87-bdb3-ee4f10c6752a",
    "8370821e-edfa-4615-ac2e-47815b740f40",
    "7c69cac1-4a70-4170-8251-cde3762fe498"
  ]
}
```

In order to get something like:

```yaml
"another group admins":
  - "da2e42c8-6423-4d32-99b5-5fc58f9f80b8"
"another group users":
  - "7c69cac1-4a70-4170-8251-cde3762fe498"
"my group admin":
  - "e08a1d9d-f108-4e87-bdb3-ee4f10c6752a"
"my group users":
  - "8370821e-edfa-4615-ac2e-47815b740f40"
"some group":
  - "e08a1d9d-f108-4e87-bdb3-ee4f10c6752a",
  - "8370821e-edfa-4615-ac2e-47815b740f40",
  - "7c69cac1-4a70-4170-8251-cde3762fe498"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The piece you are missing is `from_entries` which can build a JSON object from an array of keys and values.

Instead of:

```
jq '. | group_by(.externalGroup)[] | {(.[0].externalGroup): map(.groupId)}'
```

Try:

```
jq 'group_by(.externalGroup) | map({key:.[0].externalGroup, value:map(.groupId)}) | from_entries'
```

```
{
  "another group admins": [
    "da2e42c8-6423-4d32-99b5-5fc58f9f80b8"
  ],
  "another group users": [
    "7c69cac1-4a70-4170-8251-cde3762fe498"
  ],
  "my group admin": [
    "e08a1d9d-f108-4e87-bdb3-ee4f10c6752a"
  ],
  "my group users": [
    "8370821e-edfa-4615-ac2e-47815b740f40"
  ],
  "some group": [
    "e08a1d9d-f108-4e87-bdb3-ee4f10c6752a",
    "8370821e-edfa-4615-ac2e-47815b740f40",
    "7c69cac1-4a70-4170-8251-cde3762fe498"
  ]
}
```

I made the following changes:

- Removed the `. |` at the beginning because it doesn't change anything.
- Removed the `[]` and used `map(...)` instead, because we want to keep things in an array to feed to `from_entries`.
- Instead of assembling a one-entry object, we create `{key:..., value:...}` pairs to feed to `from_entries`.

---

Actually, I just checked and was slightly surprised to discover that `add` is actually a bit faster than `from_entries` even for very long lists. If you use `add` you need to change even less of your solution.

```
jq 'group_by(.externalGroup) | map({(.[0].externalGroup):map(.groupId)}) | add'
```

Adding together objects combines their contents together. I tested with  a 250,000 element list and it was slightly faster than `from_entries`. Given that it's also shorter and in my opinion pretty much just as clear, I think it's worthy of consideration.

Comment: Oh man. I was so close. I tried a combination of all those and was just missing some pieces here and there. I even tried what you suggested and mapped it with key-value pairs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. An alternative worth considering for producing yaml is `gojq`, the Go implementation of jq, e.g.

```
   gojq --yaml-output '
     group_by(.externalGroup) 
    | map({(.[0].externalGroup):map(.groupId)}) | add'
```

2. To avoid the overhead of `map`, you could use the following generic stream-oriented `add` that works for objects or arrays just as well as for numbers:

```
    gojq --yaml-output '
      def add(s): reduce s as $x (null; . + $x);
      add( group_by(.externalGroup)[] 
           | {(.[0].externalGroup):map(.groupId)})'
```

Comment: Interesting. Ill have to take a look at gojq.